# What is the benefit of using sqlite3_data_count() over sqlite3_column_count() in the SQLite C API?

Tags: c, api, sqlite

After reading the docs, it seems the the function sqlite3_column_count does all the same, but doesn't have the restrictions that sqlite3_data_count has.

Why would I ever want to use sqlite3_data_count over sqlite3_column_count? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sqlite3_data_count` returns the number of values (columns) of the currently executing statement.
With no results it returns 0.

`sqlite3_column_count` on the other hand, returns always the number of columns, with or without results.

Which one you'll use depends on whether you must get the number of columns or not.

Comment: I'm still confused. Did you mean that sqlite3_data_count actually returns the total number of rows in the result set, and not columns?

Answer (score 13):

I've looked up the sources of the two functions:

```
/*
** Return the number of columns in the result set for the statement pStmt.
*/
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_column_count(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt){
  Vdbe *pVm = (Vdbe *)pStmt;
  return pVm ? pVm->nResColumn : 0;
}

/*
** Return the number of values available from the current row of the
** currently executing statement pStmt.
*/
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_data_count(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt){
  Vdbe *pVm = (Vdbe *)pStmt;
  if( pVm==0 || pVm->pResultSet==0 ) return 0;
  return pVm->nResColumn;
}
```

Now it is clear what the difference is, so NickD was right.

By the way, the documentation is horrible: ["The sqlite3_data_count(P) the number of columns in the of the result set of prepared statement P."](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/data_count.html)  That's not even correct English, the comments that come with the function definitions are much better.

Comment: Sometimes we have to check the source :) +1 for checking it out. I agree that this part of the documentation isn't clear enough.

Comment: Sorry this is slightly off topic but it is related. I feel like for any given prepared statement that its result column count will always stay the same (even when using `prepare_v2` whereby the statement's SQL text content always stays the same). So I hope that it should suffice to call `sqlite3_column_count` a single time after the statement is prepared initially? (as opposed to calling it after every call to `sqlite3_step` for instance which I see a lot of sample code does)