# count rows result set data

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a SELECT query, and I would like to know the number of rows.

I tried:

```
sqlite3_data_count(statement);
```

but it always returns 0 as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite computes the result rows on the fly, so you the number of rows is not known before you have actually read all those rows.

You could execute a separate query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (original query)`, but this would mean that the query is executed twice.

Instead, you should use a data structure that grows dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3_data_count` is not counts row but counts columns.

`sqlite3_data_count` returns the number of values (columns) of the currently executing statement. With no results it returns 0.
[LINK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228159/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-sqlite3-data-count-over-sqlite3-column-count-in)
You can verify it in .h doc for [sqlite3_data_count()](http://code.google.com/p/pldatabase/source/browse/trunk/Dependencies/SQLite/sqlite3.h?r=404).

To count number of rows you can use following:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mytable"`

Comment: I am not sure but, You may use this `sqlite3_get_table()`